# cobbler injecting ~'s into reposync for ubuntu, causing failures

Tags: cobbler

Cobbler 2.8.0
OS: centos 6.6

when trying to run reposync, it fails on ubuntu repos, with the following command:

```
/usr/bin/debmirror --nocleanup --verbose ~ --ignore-release-gpg ~ --method=http --host=archive.ubuntu.com --root=/ubuntu --dist=trusty,trusty-updates,trusty-security --section=main,universe /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/ubuntu-14.04.4-x86_64 --nosource -a amd64
```

there are 2 "~" in there, that don't correspond to anything in the repo settings:
[image][image]

if I manually run this via

```
/usr/bin/debmirror --nocleanup --verbose --ignore-release-gpg --method=http --host=archive.ubuntu.com --root=/ubuntu --dist=trusty,trusty-updates,trusty-security --section=main,universe /var/www/cobbler/repo_mirror/ubuntu-14.04.4-x86_64 --nosource -a amd64
```

it works... any idea where the tilde's are coming from?

Comment: Could it be a hidden/invisible character from cutting and pasting?